# Joda Time, Get week days

Tags: java, jodatime

How to make the local date count only week date?

For example

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate();
date.plusDays(10); //it returns plus days including sat and sun as 2013-03-21
//i am looking for a way
date.plusDays(10); //should return as 2013-03-26
```

I am look for a way to remove the weekends?

Answer (score 24):

Use the `getDayOfWeek()` method.   Return will be as follows.   Inorder to get only week days.. you just need to check whether the return value is less than or equal to 5.

```
public static final int MONDAY = 1;
public static final int TUESDAY = 2;
public static final int WEDNESDAY = 3;
public static final int THURSDAY = 4;
public static final int FRIDAY = 5;
public static final int SATURDAY = 6;
public static final int SUNDAY = 7;
```

Comment: Just for info, if you want to acces those constants directly these are in `org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants`.

Comment: Why the first day starts at `1` instead of `0` I'll never know... That caused me a good hour or so of trouble...

Comment: it matches the java.time.DayOfWeek, so you can use it instead. Like: DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.getValue()

Answer (score 5):

```
LocalDate newDate = new LocalDate();
    int i=0;
    while(i<days)//days == as many as u wanted
    {
        newDate = newDate.plusDays(1);
        System.out.println("new date"+newDate);
        if(newDate.getDayOfWeek()<=5)
        {
            i++;
        }

    }
```