# how to calculate number of days between two dates excluding weekend java

Tags: java, date

Hi, i try this code to have days of works (including weekends) , so how can i exlude weekends between two dates ?

```
public long getDifferenceDays(Date d1, Date d2) {
  long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
  long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  return diffDays;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit outdated but check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171968/calculating-dates-given-two-dates-excluding-weekend

Comment: Try here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600034/calculate-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-java

Comment: try this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338196/joda-time-get-week-days

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will work for you

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date1 = df.parse("10/08/2013");
    Date date2 = df.parse("21/08/2013");
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);
    cal2.setTime(date2);

    int numberOfDays = 0;
    while (cal1.before(cal2)) {
        if ((Calendar.SATURDAY != cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
           &&(Calendar.SUNDAY != cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))) {
            numberOfDays++;
        }
        cal1.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }
    System.out.println(numberOfDays);
```

Live [Demo](http://ideone.com/c580EE)

Out put

```
7
```

Comment: Easy to understand solution. Add 1 to final `numberOfDays` (after the while loop) to include end day. Thanks for this!